# Update in access with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm making an invoice making software where I have 2 tables 1 for invoice and another for invoice items.
Now problem is if user wants to edit previous invoice and wanted to add some more items or remove some items I wrote query of update set but it needs to be insert also my update query updates all data to same as it is.

here is my update items query

```
Public Sub update_items()
    ds.Clear()
    str = ""

    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cn.Close()
    End If

    DBConfig.conn()
    cn.Open()

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "update invoice_items set [item_name]=@item_name,[qty]=@qty,[rate]=@rate where [invoice_id]=@invoice_id and [item_code]=@itemcode"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice_id", invoice_id.Text.ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_code", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


    Next
End Sub
```

my data is in datagridview which has one combobox too.Here is how my vb form looks like [image: Invoice page] Here when page loads in side dgv data loads from table called item where item name is combobox and other calculation happens on bases of price and quantity. When it saves all of the data stores in to two diffrent tables one is invoice and second is invoice_items where I store data with item name, quantity, price, invoice no. Rest data is stored in invoice table.
Now where user wants to edit data he has to search with invoice no on search click I get data from invoice table as well as invoice_items and display as it is now I want to update all the data on update click data updates in invoice table perfectly but it starts problem with invoice_items table. which I had written before.

Comment: Using table adapters will manage the update/insert for you.  That aside in the current pattern, you will need a way to determine if it is a new row or an update to an existing row and then execute the correct command type.  Assuming you've got the DataGridView bound to a datatable (Unclear since you're iterating the DGV rows) you could use the rowstate

Comment: You've also mentioned removing items in you question, if by removing you mean delete from the DB, that is another command you will need to execute.

Comment: Also point out, you got some very valid feedback on your question yesterday suggesting data adapters, Parameters.AddWithValue() and global connection objects.  Any reason why you've chosen to ignore that an carry on with some pretty dicey practices?

Comment: Actully I'm new to data adapters and client wants basic version so i'm planning to learn and the impliment in next version. can you help me for one single shot tutorial for it so I learn and impliment it asap?

Comment: Question edited pleaes can you check it again

Comment: IMO data adapter are the basics and what you should be a) learning and b) implementing . Using the more direct SQL command type pattern you have here, is probably more of a when you hit a limitation of data adapters.  The answer you've got here is in my view a pretty solid start.  after that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter is probably as good as place as any to start

Answer (score 2):

Golly, I suggest you consider using the dataset desinger. (or Entity frame work desinger). Dataset designer works much like EF, but it will auto matic bind and wire up for you automatic all of the data operations.

The results are VERY much like data bound ms-access forms.

so, if I use the data set designer, then I can drag + drop fields on to the form.
and you even get a navigation bar with record movement, and save, and add and delete features ALL automatic done for you.

So, you get say a form like this:

[image]

Same goes for datagrids - you can edit, add or even delete.

All of above works with without you having to write code.

Same goes for say a datagrid.

Say we drop in a button (to save), and then a data grid.

We have this:

[image]

Total code for this - inclding the save button code is now this:

```
Private Sub HotelGridEdit_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    LoadGrid()

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description, Active FROM tblHotelsA 
            ORDER BY HotelName"
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = rstData
        End Using
    End Using


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' save all edits, and new rows, and deletes
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description, Active FROM tblHotelsA 
            ORDER BY HotelName"
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daC As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(DataGridView1.DataSource)

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Note the save code. We send all edits, deletes, and even addtions in one shot.

So, you don't need (nor want) to write code just for a insert, just for edit, and just for adding). You can get the .net system and the form to do all of this work for you.

Comment: Question edited please can you check it again

Comment: Even with a master form, and then say a child data table + grid to display that data? That does not take off the table that the two parts (main form) and the child data (data grid) cannot used adaptors here. Using adaptors on the form would allow one save button to save edits/add/delete in the grid + form edits back to the database, and you would not require writing of vb insert, and delete and edit statements in code - only a final save button that sends both form part, and the grid part back to the database. So, you need to find some data binding tutorials, since that can reduce code here

Comment: This sounds so cool any perticular keywords that I have to look for my work to do to find tutorials or please share if you have any thanks alot

Comment: hum, "vb.net databinding forms dataset designer" should produce results. I think the "big" decision is do you want to start using the dataset designer. It has a learning curve, but not too bad, but the end result is data bound forms (much like access). So edits, deletes and even record navigation can all be automatic wired up for you.